# Keep special characters in XML

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, special-characters

I have a requirement where I need to read an XML file that may contain special characters. But I need to keep those special characters "as-is". However, after calling XDocument.Load(), `&apos;` is turned to ' and `&amp;` to &.

Here is what the XML file may look like:

```
 <root>
    <child>This is a text with special character such as &apos; and &amp;</child>
 </root>

XDocument xDoc = null;
xDocument = XDocument.Load("myFile.xml", LoadOptions.SetBaseUri | LoadOptions.SetLineInfo | LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

I've tried with encoding, but with no success. For example:

```
using (StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader("myFile.xml", Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
{
    xDocument = XDocument.Load(oReader);
}
```

or

```
xDocument = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText("myFile.xml", Encoding.UTF8));
```

Is there anything else that I can try?
Thanks.

Comment: You have no choice: You have to XML encode them properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "as-is"? What's happening? Please show a short but complete example - we have no idea what your document looks like or what you're observing.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added an example of what the XML file might look like.

Comment: Okay, well you've got XML entities in there - those have particular meanings in XML. Fundamentally, your XML of `&apos;` doesn't represent text of an ampersand followed by "apos;"... it represents text of "'". If you want to represent an ampersand followed by "apos;" you need `&amp;apos;`. Don't try to fight against it - you're meant to have an XML document. You should make that XML document represent what you want it to represent, rather than treating it as a text file with angle brackets in.